# Spinner not working (Android)

Tags: android, spinner

I have made a simple demo for spinners in android with one activity. I have tried the following code but it's not working. when I run this app on my phone it shows:- "Unfortunately the app has stopped working "

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner);

  ArrayAdapter  Adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                    (this,R.array.days,R.layout.support_simp
                    le_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(Adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long 
l) {
   TextView mytext=(TextView)view;
    Toast.makeText(this,"you selected"+mytext.getText(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**XML code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rakib.myapplication.MainActivity">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp">

</Spinner>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
String[] myarray =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days);         

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simp le_spinner_dropdown_item, myarray);
```

(or)

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
           myarray); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Use this code to **get values from the spinner**.

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"you selected"+parent.getItemAtPosition(pos),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, your second solution is working but Toast doesn't work!!after I have clicked the item in spinner nothing has shown!! @Gowthaman M